# Import error in ModelType in genai library in python while running my code

Tags: python, openai-api

I am getting import error for ModelType while running it from  IBM genai SDK in python.

> from genai.schemas import GenerateParams, ModelType, ReturnOptions

I am using python 3.10 and latest pip version as per documentation. Went through documentaion but unable to find any mention of ModelType class.

documentation: https://ibm.github.io/ibm-generative-ai/rst_source/genai.model.html#genai.model.Model.available

Can someone please help?